# can't set cookie and render template

Tags: cookies, rack

I try to set cookie and render template. The cookie works, but template doesn't. I receive:

```
<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>
```

What do I do wrong?

```
class Racker
  def self.call(env)
    new(env).response.finish
  end

  def initialize(env)
    @request = Rack::Request.new(env)
  end

  def response
    case @request.path
    when '/new_game'
     Rack::Response.new do |response|  
     response.set_cookie('name', @request.params['name'])  
     render('new_game')
    end
    ...
    end
  end

  def render(template)
    path = File.expand_path("./views/#{template}.html.erb")
    ERB.new(File.read(path)).result(binding)
  end
end
```